# After using Magento Wordpress integration Fishpig, my homepage shows blank white screen,

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I have installed Fishpig Wordpress plugin to my Magento website. Blog was working fine but my website homepage shows nothing but a blank screen.

You can see www.jrdecal.com, it only works when you try www.jrdecal.com/index.php

Then I uninstalled that extension but still the same problem. How to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: it looks to me like it could be htaccess... where do you have installed your wordpress? is rewrite mode enable? can you login to your wordpress through magento's backend?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just follow [fishpig](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/#docs) instruction. My WordPress is in the same server. My rewrite modes OK.<br/>                                                 <code><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Before uninstall my WordPress part with integration was fine.